# Compile using Direct X June 2010 SDK on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, directx, windows-8

I want to use the June 2010 SDK rather than the Windows 8 SDK to compile my DirectX code in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 Release Candidate.

The problem is that since the DirectX 8 SDKs are in the same folder as the Windows SDK, I don't know which include/library folders I can change.

As it stands, seemingly nothing I change in the directory settings or the linker settings solves the issue of something or another referring to the Windows 8 SDK, which causes a bunch of redefinition warnings among other things.

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: What is the real problem you want to solve?

Comment: @BoPersson I want to compile some SlimDX stuff from the SVN -- specifically, [their SpriteBatch implementation](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Flite%2FSlimDX.Toolkit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the easiest way, but I ended up installing VS2010 and compiling that way.

As a side note, the DirectX June 2010 SDK fails to install correctly (probably for Windows 8 reasons), but it leaves the `\program files` folder intact when it finishes -- so all the .libs and .hs are there to use.